# Excel VBA - For Each - In & end(xltoright)

Tags: excel, vba

So here's what I got so far:

```
Sub SortByGen()
Dim Gen As Range

For Each Gen In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:G3")
    If Gen.Value = "XXX" Then
        Gen.EntireColumn.Copy _
            Worksheets("XXX").Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn
     If Gen.Value = "YYY" Then
        Gen.EntireColumn.Copy _
            Worksheets("YYY").Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn
    End If
Next Gen

End Sub
```

I'm trying to sort certain columns from one worksheet to multiple worksheets based on a certain criterion. I accidentally placed a values on

```
Worksheets("XXX").Range("B2") and Worksheets("YYY").Range("B2")
```

so when the

```
.end(xltoright)
```

ran, the code worked. Now when I try to get rid of the values in B2, the code will get an error.

Comment: Isn't it because of the second `If`, which should be `ElseIf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `xlToRight` and you're starting from the last occupied cell in that row then it will go to the very end of the row: you can't offset 1 more column from there...

Use this instead:

```
Gen.EntireColumn.Copy _
Worksheets("XXX").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn
```